# I can't install 'tunnel-vmc-plugin' to enable tunnelling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud-foundry, tunnel, tunneling, vmc

I deployed a Rails app on Cloud Foundry, and every time I run vmc tunnel, I keep getting the following error:

```
Please install 'tunnel-vmc-plugin' to enable tunnelling.
Pardon the extra step; it can't be a direct dependency because it
requires native compilation.
```

Can anyone tell what's going on here? Thanks.

Here is the additional info:

```
Rails 3.2.8
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
vmc 0.5.0.beta.10
```

Here are all the gems:

```
actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8)
addressable (2.3.2, 2.2.8)
arel (3.0.2)
async_sinatra (0.5.0)
bootstrap-sass (2.1.0.1)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.3)
caldecott-client (0.0.2)
cf-uaa-lib (1.3.7)
cfoundry (0.5.0, 0.4.20, 0.4.19)
chunky_png (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
clouseau (0.0.2)
compass (0.12.2)
compass-rails (1.0.3)
console-vmc-plugin (0.0.4)
daemons (1.1.9)
em-http-request (0.3.0)
em-websocket (0.3.8)
erubis (2.7.0)
escape_utils (0.2.4)
eventmachine (1.0.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
fssm (0.2.10, 0.2.9)
haml (3.1.7)
haml-rails (0.3.5)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
interact (0.5.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.0, 2.1.4)
json (1.7.6, 1.7.5, 1.6.7)
json_pure (1.6.7)
mail (2.4.4)
manifests-vmc-plugin (0.5.0, 0.4.19)
mime-types (1.20.1, 1.19)
mothership (0.5.0, 0.3.5)
multi_json (1.5.0, 1.4.0)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
open4 (1.3.0)
Platform (0.4.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
POpen4 (0.1.4)
rack (1.4.4, 1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-protection (1.3.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (10.0.3)
rdoc (3.12)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
sass (3.2.5, 3.2.4)
sass-rails (3.2.6, 3.2.5)
sinatra (1.3.4)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thin (1.5.0)
thor (0.17.0, 0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tunnel-dummy-vmc-plugin (0.0.2)
tunnel-vmc-plugin (0.2.0, 0.1.11)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
vmc (0.5.0.beta.10)
yui-compressor (0.9.6)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vmc tunnel
```

...should be independent of any apps you have deployed. All you need is
one or more services ("vmc create service" - once done, you can tunnel to it)

Tunneling requires caldecott, so make sure you have followed,
[Tunneling to a Cloud Foundry Service with Caldecott](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html)

```
gem list tunnel
```

...should give you a list of your tunnel plugins

I just updated vmc to beta.12 and it depends on tunnel-vmc-plugin (~> 0.2),
so I removed all other versions.

If you didn't get the tunnel plugin,

```
gem uninstall vmc
```

then

```
gem install vmc --pre
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had several services created prior to running 'vmc tunnel' but I think caldecott might have been missing (as per the enclosed gem list above. Anyway, adding caldecott did not immediate solve the issue because there was conflicts among cfoundry 0.5.0, 0.4.20 and 0.4.19. So I had to remove everything including vmc, console, caldecott, tunnel... and reinstall one by one. Problem solved

Comment: hey i'm facing the same conflicts. can you please detail out exactly what you did? i'm not being able to run the `vmc tunnel` at all.

Comment: please tell me what all gems you installed along with their versions

Comment: Can you list all the gems that you install for vmc and tunnel? It is helpful to see what you have installed. Also I would suggest to uninstall vmc and all related gems. then reinstall them one after another.